# Jenkins pipeline parameter being evaluated to previous value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've got a pipeline which builds software, with a parameter used for the version.

The parameter defaults to a Groovy expression evaluating to the current date.

But when I run it, the value it's using is actually the date of the previous build.

Example:

- Build #17 (25 Mar 2022, 10:37:57) prints `2022-03-25T10:37:51.471369100`
- Build #18 (25 Mar 2022, 11:08:33) prints `2022-03-25T10:37:57.857506500`
- Build #19 (25 Mar 2022, 11:09:52) prints `Build version 2022-03-25T11:08:33.802312`

Pipeline Script:

```js
    pipeline {
        agent any
        parameters {
            string(
                name: "BUILD_VERSION",
                defaultValue: "Build version "+java.time.LocalDateTime.now()
                )
            }
            stages {
                stage("Print") {
                    steps {
                        echo params.BUILD_VERSION
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What am I missing? How can I default the parameter to the date it's executed?

Comment: No the behaviour looks correct because ```java.time.LocalDateTime.now()``` returns the currentTime and date.

Comment: @DashrathMundkar yes, I understand what now() returns, but my problem is that it seems to being executed but it’s value not used, and instead the previous executions’ value is used.

Comment: @jakg Yes, it is the value (timestamp) at the time of the last evaluation, and that evaluation is the time when the job/pipeline was built last time. That's the thing with pipelines: the defaults expressions are evaluated in the first build, and stored for the next build. That's why only beginning with 2nd build will Jenkins know that the job has parameters (!) and that those parameters have default valures.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the the `defaultValue` attribute of the string parameter you are actually setting the default value for the next execution of the project, not for the current one - as the default value is updated only after the build started to run with the given parameters.
Therefore the next build will be executed with the value set by the previous one.

To overcome this you need to define a parameter that is updated before the builds starts to run, and then the build will use that parameter in the execution.
One way to do it is with the [Extended Choice Parameter Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin) which will generated the default value on runtime when you click the **Build With Parameters** in your job. This way the default time value will be used for the current running build.
Here is the code example:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        extendedChoice(name: 'BUILD_VERSION', type: 'PT_TEXTBOX',
                       defaultGroovyScript: 'return java.time.LocalDateTime.now().toString()')
    }
    stages {
        stage("Print") {
            steps {
                echo params.BUILD_VERSION
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this. It is amazing... Is this how modern software tools are??? Speechless!!!

Comment: I knew that in C++ sometimes I may shoot myself in the foot, but in this case with Jenkins it looks like a headshot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be sufficient, if the timestamp doesn't need to be editable?

```js
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
String BUILD_VERSION_TXT

pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'BUILD_VERSION', defaultValue: "Build version")
    }
    stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
            steps {
                script {
                    BUILD_VERSION_TXT = params.BUILD_VERSION + ' ' + java.time.LocalDateTime.now()
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Print") {
            steps {
                echo BUILD_VERSION_TXT
            }
        }
    }
}
```